# Excel counting seperate values in the same cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a excel sheet in which I need to count diffrent values from one cell.
The ones and zeros vary as well as the amount of `<br>` that seperated them. I need to count the ones and zeros seperatly. `10000010011<br>10101010101<br>01100111000<br>101101010110` In this example I need four values indicating the amount of ones and zeros. Here it would be: zeros1:7 ones1:4, zeros2: 5 ones2:6, zeros3: 6 ones3: 5, zeros4: 5 ones4: 7. I really would appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: I don't get how you arrive at _zeros1:7 ones1:4, zeros2: 5 ones2:6, zeros3: 6 ones3: 5, zeros4: 5 ones4: 7_.  Four values indicating the amount of ones and zeros - should that be two sets of four values?  e.g. Before the first `<br>` you have 4:7 (4 1's and 7 0's) .  So the final figure should be _4:7, 6:5, 5:6, 7:5_?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Yes exactly thats how the final figure should look like!

Comment: I'd suggest undoing the edit to your question and adding it as your accepted answer.  It may not be the fastest or most technical way of doing it, but it works for you and that's what matters... no luck with the VBA route?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook since I had to manually prepare the data anyway I wasn't sure if this might interfere with the VBA route, and because I didn't understand the code (I'm not familiar with code in general), I choose to do it manually!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear all thanks for your suggestions! Basically I have deceided to it the simple but more lengthly way in splitting the cell (text in columns).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each binary is always 11 digits:

Parse your data Text to Columns/Fixed width with breaks around the angled brackets, then skip the `<br>` columns and apply formulae such as:

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,1,""))
```

copied across to suit and repeat with `,0,` in place of `,1,` or just subtract the above results from `11`.

Comment: No they vary, not sure how. Would this knowledge help? In total (entire cell) ones vary 20 - 40 and zeros vary 20 – 28 , so in total there is a variation of 40 – 68. Not sure if this helps

Comment: You can skip the "always 11" by replacing "<br>" with loads of spaces, then `TRIM` a `MID`, e.g. `=TRIM(Mid(SUBSTITUTE($A$1,"<br>",REPT(" ",999)),1+999*(Row()-1),999))` will provide 1 entry per row

Comment: @pnuts Perhaps:  But in Office 365 with the ability to use `CONCAT` or `TEXTJOIN` in an Array Formula you can run it as a 1-cell formula to give dynamically the full output OP wanted.  Your option is probably simpler if it's "data is fixed and not going to change" though

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LEFT and RIGHT functions in combination with SEARCH to split the cell by "<br>". You can put them in a row (into multiple cells), so that the next one takes output of the previous one as the input.

So A1 would be your input and then put `=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("<br>",A1,1) - 3)` into A2 (this will remove everything before first "<br>"). Then put the same formula, but with `A2` instead of `A1` everywhere (that will remove everything before second "<br>"), and so on.

More info: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/split-text-into-different-columns-with-functions-49ec57f9-3d5a-44b2-82da-50dded6e4a68

Comment: Thanks but somehow it doesn't work. I put the input in A1 and your formula in A2 but it showed a error message. Also since i have a whole column of these zeros and ones, it would be better to put the formula into the next column (B1 for example).

Comment: There was a ; in the search string which shouldn't be there. I edited the answer. Please note that this should only copy everything after the first &lt;br&gt; to the next column, so you still need to use one more LEFT to get the part you want. Putting this into a columns is not problem, it should work the same way. Also the names of the functions may be different in your language.

Answer (score 0):

If a VBA answer is ok you could use this function:

With `10000010011<br>10101010101<br>01100111000<br>101101010110` in cell `A1` the formula `=Count1And0(A1)` will return `4:7, 6:5, 5:6, 7:5`

```
Public Function Count1And0(Target As Range) As String

    Dim vSplit As Variant
    Dim vNum As Variant
    Dim sFinal As String
    Dim lCount As Long

    vSplit = Split(Target, "<br>")

    For Each vNum In vSplit
        lCount = Len(vNum) - Len(Replace(vNum, "0", ""))
        sFinal = sFinal & Len(vNum) - lCount & ":" & lCount & ", "
    Next vNum

    Count1And0 = Left(sFinal, Len(sFinal) - 2)

End Function
```

Comment: This site doesn't seem to have a _where do I put it_ type question that I can find after 5 seconds of searching...  [This site](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/12/06/add-run-vba-macro-excel/) seems to explain it ok - you just need to insert it into a _code module_ and remember to save as _xlsm_.